# How to concatenate or merge series to dataframe without duplicating column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate a Series returned from a function to a Dataframe, but I don't want the columns to be duplicated. How can I accomplish this? The full dataset is ~100k rows, and there are about 100 subsets (defined in a loop with masks), so hopefully, there is a computationally fast solution. Using Python 3.7

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

def myfcn(row, data, val):
    z1 = row['y'] + val
    z2 = row['x']*row['y']
    return pd.Series(
        {'fancy_column_name1': z1, 
         'fancy_column_name2': z2/val},
        name=row.name
    )
    

col1 = [1, 1.5, 3.1, 3.4, 2, -1]
col2 = [1, -3, 2, 8, 2.5, -1.3]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
display(df)

### In the real case, this is all in a loop with many subsets that 
### are created with masks & specific criteria; this is 
### simplified here
df_subset = df.iloc[[0,2,3]]
#display(df_subset)
out = df_subset.apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(df_subset, 100))
df = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)

df_subset2 = df.iloc[[5]]
out = df_subset2.apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(df_subset2, 250))
df = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)
display(df)
```

**Here is the parent dataframe "df"**
[image] 
**Here is the current output** 
[image]
**Here is the wanted output**
[image]
How can I remove the duplicated column names, collapsing the data into the same column? I want to retain the numbers, not the NaNs. There will never be an instance where where there is more than one number to retain in a row, but there may be an instance where there are no numbers (so then, retain NaN).

Comment: You are looking for `merge` not `concat`

Comment: I tried `merge = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` and `merge = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')` but those did not work

Comment: `pd.merge` is a heavy operation. Instead of the `pd.concat` just use `df = df.combine_first(out)`. It combines the 2 dataframes by filling null values in one DataFrame with non-null values from other DataFrame. check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **pandas.DataFrame.combine_first:** Combine two DataFrame objects by filling null values in one DataFrame with non-null values from other DataFrame. The row and column indexes of the resulting DataFrame will be the union of the two.

Just replace the `df = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)` with -

```
df = df.combine_first(out)
```

[image]

More details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

---

The reason why your order is not retained is because `out` has only 2 columns. Those are the ones that replace the values of nans first. Therefore they become the first ones. You can insert a blank x and y ahead of out to solve this -

```
out.insert(0, 'x', 0)
out.insert(1, 'y', 0)
df = df.combine_first(out)
```

Add this to the loop and me know if your column order is now fixed.

Comment: this is a neat trick, my only complaint is that it reorders the columns

Comment: Well, you can reorder them back by simply holding the cols before. check my updated answer.

Comment: pd.merge is a heavy heavy operation and totally unnecessary for what you want to do. I dont think that should be the right answer but the rest is up to you :)

Comment: How do I add the new column names to `cols`? The OP is a simplified case, but the subsets are created in a loop, so `cols = df.columns` should be outside the loop, then `cols` is edited to add my two new column names, then do `df=df[cols]`

Comment: the `df.columns` part is just for reordering. new columns get automatically added with `df.combine_first(out)`. Once you have run your loop, you can explicitly create a `col` variable with the list of your columns in order and then use that in `df[col]` outside the loop.

Comment: I did that initially, and the new columns weren't added. `cols = df.columns` needs to be at the top, after `df = pd.DataFrame(list...` because everything else below that is in a loop in  the real case. (In other words, `cols = df.columns` cannot be after `df_subset = df.iloc[[0,2,...` because then will always be in a loop, and that is silly -- OP edited for this.)

Comment: oh you dont need to add `cols = df.columns` anywhere. maybe if you could update your question with the for loop I would love to help you solve it in an efficient way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228498/discussion-between-a11-and-akshay-sehgal).

Comment: getting the original column order `cols = list(df.columns)` at the beginning; doing work; then at the end running `cols.extend(['fancy_column_name1', 'fancy_column_name2']` and then `df = df[cols]` does the trick, it saves out perfectly. Thank you VERY much for your help and patience!

Comment: Ah great, that's a good solution! upvoting for the great fix!

Answer (score 1):

Do your calculations of sub-setting together, then append those out columns together and then merge into your main dataframe. I modified your code a bit:

```
def myfcn(row, data, val):
    z1 = row['y'] + val
    z2 = row['x']*row['y']
    return pd.Series(
        {'fancy_column_name1': z1, 
         'fancy_column_name2': z2/val},
        name=row.name
    )
    

col1 = [1, 1.5, 3.1, 3.4, 2, -1]
col2 = [1, -3, 2, 8, 2.5, -1.3]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2)), columns=['x', 'y'])

df_subset = df.iloc[[0,2,3]]
#display(df_subset)
out1 = df_subset.apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(df_subset, 100))
df_subset2 = df.iloc[[5]]
out2 = df_subset2.apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(df_subset2, 250))
out = out1.append(out2)

df = pd.merge(df, out, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left")
print(df)
```

output:

```
     x    y  fancy_column_name1  fancy_column_name2
0  1.0  1.0               101.0              0.0100
1  1.5 -3.0                 NaN                 NaN
2  3.1  2.0               102.0              0.0620
3  3.4  8.0               108.0              0.2720
4  2.0  2.5                 NaN                 NaN
5 -1.0 -1.3               248.7              0.0052
```